# Why can't I access a declared variable in the global scope

Tags: javascript, scope, this

```js
        var bar = {
            myName: 'bar',
            printName: function () {
                console.log(this.myName)
            }
        }
        function foo() {
            let myName = 'foo'
            return bar.printName
        }
        let myName = 'outer'
        let _printName = foo()
        _printName()
        bar.printName()
```

Why the result of the first function execution is undefined ? I thought the result would be 'outer', and why output 'outer' after changing let to var ? This is so confusing, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the result of the first function execution is undefined ?

Because you don't bind `this` to anything in the function call (you neither have `objectThatWillBecomeThis.printName()` nor `printName.call(objectThatWillBecomeThis)`). In strict mode, this would crash because `this` would be `undefined` then and you'd try to read `undefined.myName`. But since you didn't enable strict mode, the legacy behavior is active in which `this` - when not explicitly set - will be set to the global object. However, the global object doesn't have any property `myName` (in the browser: there is no `window.myName`) so the result is `undefined`.

> why output 'outer' after changing let to var ?

Because if you run this code in the global scope, `var` outside of any other scope will create a property on the global object (`window.myName`). `let` [doesn't do that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#scoping_rules):

> At the top level of programs and functions, `let`, unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object. For example:
>
> ```js
> var x = 'global';
> let y = 'global';
> console.log(this.x); // "global"
> console.log(this.y); // undefined
> ```

If you'd move the code inside a function, it wouldn't work either, by the way, because the `var` (or `let`, doesn't matter now) statement would just create a local variable in the function and not a property on the global object, so there would be no way to access it through *any* object's `myName` property.